# How to create multiple 'dynamic add/remove inputs' on one page?

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic

I am using this script with jquery for my dynamic add/remove input field:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var i = $('input').size() + 1;

$('#add').click(function() {
    $('<div><input type="text" class="field" name="dynamic[]" value="' + i + '" /></div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs');
    i++;
});

$('#remove').click(function() {
if(i > 1) {
    $('.field:last').remove();
    i--;
}
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
while(i > 2) {
    $('.field:last').remove();
    i--;
}
});

});
</script>
```

My input field code:

```
<a href="#" id="add">Add</a> | <a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a> | <a href="#" id="reset">reset</a>
<div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="dynamic[]" class="field" placeholder=""/></div>
```

So everything works fine with this code, but I can't seem to figure out how to create more than one working box in the same webpage.

I tried adding numbers to the name field, (like dynamic2, dynamic3, etc) but it doesn't do anything for me.

Is there a way to create another one of the same functioning input box, but with a different assigned name so I can POST it to PHP individually?

I am using this PHP for posting:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['dynamic'] as $value) {
echo "$value <br />"; // change this to what you want to do with the data
}
?>
```

PHP posting works fine, but I can only do ONE input group at a time. I want to be able to do multiple on the same page.

I got the original script from this webpage:
http://papermashup.com/dynamically-add-form-inputs-and-submit-using-jquery/

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jrgY/) implementation if doing the same for multiple blocks

all you have to do is create multiple blocks (3 blocks are given in the example) in html and you are ready to go.

in PHP you have to access it using

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST)){
        echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST['dynamic1']);echo '</pre>';
        echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST['dynamic2']);echo '</pre>';
        echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST['dynamic3']);echo '</pre>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! That is exactly what I needed! I just have one more question. I was able to output it to a PHP file using your code, but I am wondering how to output ALL the input fields for each box onto the code. For instance, once I add 3 fields to the FIRST block, and output that block on PHP, can I output all the three inputs I made? With the "foreach" code on PHP I was able to do that, but with your PHP output code I am not sure how to!

Comment: when u give the name of input fields with **[]** as suffix then php will group them into array and `print_r` can be used to output array content. instead of fetching the count of each array, looping through all the fields and and making it complex because its not compulsory to have same number of fields in every block, I am making use of print_r since u just want to show output without any processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
for($i=0;isset($_POST);$i++)
{
    echo $_POST['group1'][$i];
    echo $_POST['group2'][$i];
}
?>
```

this way multiple post

Comment: thanks for your reply! I wanted to know if it is possible to create multiple separate input fields and have them individually output to a PHP. For instance, I want input name="number1" to output to PHP POST[number1] and input name="number2" to output to PHP POST [number2]. Now when I try to make two diff. input names with the save script formula, it crashes! Is there a way??

Comment: I found the way around it using Anil Kumar's code, and it works great. I just need to figure out how to output the multiple fields onto the PHP. I was able to use the 'foreach' formula before. I am wondering if I can do the same with the new codes!